# Unobtrusive Validation Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write my own validation script for the first time.  I have followed several tutorials and I have gotten them working and now trying to understand the logic behind it from scratch, this is my custom one:

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DateGreaterThanTodayAttribute: ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public DateGreaterThanTodayAttribute(): base("{0} must be greater than today")
    { 
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var valueAsDate = (DateTime)value;

            if (valueAsDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }



    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationType = "dategreaterthantoday";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("today", DateTime.Now);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
}
```

JS:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dategreaterthantoday", function (value, element, params) {
if (value) {
    var valueAsDate = Date.parse(value);

    if (valueAsDate < Date.now)
        return false;
 }
return true;
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("dategreaterthantoday")
```

The server side validation works fine, but I am still a bit confused as to the parameters that must be passed on the client side code, if somebody could help me make sense of why client side validation is not working, I am not looking for just a plain solution but an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake, instead of using Date.Now, I changed it to new Date() (Javascript code), worked like a charm.